# How to run client script on on remote host and get results to the client

Tags: remote

How to run script residing on the client on a remote host and get results back to the client in one go.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
ssh host sh -s < script.sh
```

To redirect remote output to local file:

```
ssh host sh -s < script.sh > output.txt
```

Explanation:

`ssh host sh` will invoke to default shell on the remote host. The `-s` option will tell the remote shell to read commands from standard input. Lastly the redirection `< script.sh` will attach `stdin` of the remote shell to the local file `script.sh`. The last redirection in the second example `> output.txt` will attach the `stdout` of the remote shell to the local file `output.txt`.

Comment: The below script I have written to check the status of the listener of a database.

I have this file on my client (windows machine running cygwin).  I request your help in knowing how to execute this client script on the host and create a log on the host and ship the log back to the windows machine running cygwin (client).

##################
#### chk_lsnr.sh  
###################
rm -f lsnr.exist
ps -ef | grep LISTENER | grep -v grep  > lsnr.exist
if [ -s lsnr.exist ]
then
    echo "Listener is up and running"  > lsnr.log
else
echo "Alert LISTENER DOWN "  > lsnr.log
fi
rm -f lsnr.exist

Comment: Something like: `ssh host sh -s < chk_lsnr.sh && scp host:~/lsnr.log ./lsnr.log`. However, if your script would write the status messages to `stdout` instead of to a log file you could use another redirection to write the messages to a local logfile directly: `ssh host sh -s < chk_lsnr.sh > lsnr.log`.

Comment: Thomas,  Your suggestion worked like a charm!!!! I really Thank You for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try:

```
ssh host script.sh
```

Comment: That requires `script.sh` to reside on the remote host.